# Repeat Command in in excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to repeat this command in subsequent rows every 15th time.So the next one will be `J348:M348`

```
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("J318").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R303C10-((R3C2-R4C2)/(R5C2/R6C2))"
    Range("K318").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R303C11-((R3C3-R4C3)/(R5C2/R6C2))"
    Range("L318").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]"
    Range("M318").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]"
    Range("J318:M318").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J318:M332"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("J318:M332").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=0
    Range("J332").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=15
    Range("J333:M333").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("J334").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("J335").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("J334:M334").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
```

Comment: updated code with tag

Comment: You should look into using a loop, and making use of modulo. Then you don't have to selet the range every time, but can just use one formula.

Comment: how do I write it @Luuklag

Comment: Do some googling and you will find out.

Answer (score 0):

For a straight migration of your code to a looped code:

I randomly started at row 5 and used a do while loop.  You could just as easily use a for loop.  Hopefully this gives you the idea of the looping so you don't have to do it manually.

```
Public Sub Every15thRow()

Dim i As Integer
Dim iFirst, iSecond, iThird, iFourth, iFifth As Integer
'in Ex: 318, 303, 332, 333, 334
Dim MyStopCriteria As Boolean
MyStopCriteria = False
'... whatever your code does before
'...

i = 5          'start with the 5th row

Do Until MyStopCriteria = True

    iFirst = i + 15
    iSecond = i
    iThird = i + 29
    iFourth = i + 30
    iFifth = i + 31

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("J" & iFirst).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & iSecond & "C10-((R3C2-R4C2)/(R5C2/R6C2))"
    Range("K" & iFirst).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & iSecond & "C11-((R3C3-R4C3)/(R5C2/R6C2))"
    Range("L" & iFirst).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]"
    Range("M" & iFirst).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]"
    Range("J" & iFirst & ":M" & iFirst).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J" & iFirst & ":M" & iThird), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("J" & iFirst & ":M" & iFourth).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=0
    Range("J" & iThird).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=15
    Range("J" & iThird & ":M" & iThird).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("J" & iFourth).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("J" & iFourth).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("J" & iFifth & ":M" & iFifth).Select

    '...
    '... whatever else your repeating code needs to do
    '...

    i = i + 15                          'Add 15 rows

    If i > 40 Then MyStopCriteria = True
Loop

    '... whatever else your code does after repeating

End Sub
```